# Chrome 104 broke chrome.extension API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension which I'm developing, and on one tab I'm printing some text. This worked correctly until I updated Chrome to version 104.

Now this line `this.windowViews = chrome.extension.getViews({ tabId: tab.id, type: "tab" });`
returns an empty array, previously it returned a window object. Any ideas? Unfortunately the changelog is not updated for version 104 so I can't see what changes they did...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked for bug reports? I know there's a lot to wade through, but that's where I'd start

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, I found this: [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1349787&q=getviews&can=2) Looks like I have to wait for a fix..

Comment: Not surprising. Not sure why people put up with that garbage browser 